# VTK file format, polygons and vector field

Tags: vtk

I need to export both simple geometry and a vector field to some VTK files. I have managed to export the geometry, but am struggeling to figure out how to export the vector field. What is the structure/format of the file I need?

This is what I have so far (by the way, the vectors need to be arbitrarily placed, meaning that strucured grid and so on won't work):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<VTKFile type="PolyData" version="0.1" byte_order="LittleEndian">
  <PolyData>
    <Piece NumberOfPoints="8" NumberOfVerts="0" NumberOfLines="0" NumberOfStrips="0" NumberOfPolys="5">
      <Points>
        <DataArray type="Float32" NumberOfComponents="3" format="ascii">
        //point data//
        </DataArray>
      </Points>

      <Polys>
        <DataArray type="Int32" Name="connectivity" format="ascii">
        //connectivity data//
        </DataArray>

        <DataArray type="Int32" Name="offsets" format="ascii">
        //offsett data//
        </DataArray>
      </Polys>

    </Piece>
      //Need to put vector field with it's own points here//
  </PolyData>
</VTKFile>
```

**Update**: After suggestions from Chris (see answer below) I have updated the file to this form:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<VTKFile type="UnstructuredGrid" version="0.1" byte_order="LittleEndian">
  <UnstructuredGrid>
    <Piece NumberOfPoints="50" NumberOfCells="0">
      <PointData Vectors="Velocity">
        <DataArray Vectors="Velocity">
          //vector data//
        </DataArray>
      </PointData>
      <Points>
        <DataArray type="Float32" NumberOfComponents="3" format="ascii">
          //point data//
        </DataArray>
      </Points>
      <Cells/>
     <CellData/>
   </Piece>
 </UnstructuredGrid>
</VTKFile>
```

Comment: I have updated my answer to suggest using a StructuredData file, rather than UnstructuredData. StructuredData is much more appropraite and easier to work with (no need to specify cell information). Just note that when specifying the coordinates and data, these 3D arrays are flattened to 1D arrays with a flat index `idx_flat = k*(npts_x*npts_y) + j*nptr_x + i` (see [here](http://www.itk.org/Wiki/ParaView/Users_Guide/VTK_Data_Model)).

Comment: I have just noticed that you stated in your question that a structured grid won't work because the nodes of the vector need to be arbitrarily placed. Does this mean you have a grid of nodes that are not connected? If so ignore my edit (I will roll it back) and try specifiying the cell information as I suggest in the comments to the question. Otherwise StructuredData will allow you to have arbitrary node coordinates for each node.

Comment: Yeah, The nodes needs to move, and the movement is simulated, and a littlebit unpredictable. so there is no structure to them. The nodes doesn't need to connected in any way. I just need vectors to be placed at arbitrary points.

Comment: Another option is to use the legacy ASCII vtk format, because it is easy to generate from your program. Then you can convert it later to the modern VTK format using a simple Python script (e.g. see ``Utilities/vtk2xml.py`` in the vtk repository).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From you example XML file it seems that the vector field is defined at different coordinates from the nodes of your PolyData. If this is the case then you will need to use two different files. From the VTK File Format specification, which is part of the VTK User's Guide (see www.vtk.org/VTK/img/file-formats.pdf):

> By convention, each data type and file type is paired with a particular file extension.

Your vector field sounds like `UnstructuredGrid` data, where you have to specify the coordinates of the grid nodes explicitly (unlike, say `ImageGrid`s, where the node coordinates are defined implicitly by the spacing and the extent of the data). This obviously cannot go in a PolyData VTK file (see the second line of your example XML file).

So try writing a new file for your vector data with the outline (taken from the file formats document):

```
<VTKFile type="UnstructuredGrid" ...>
  <UnstructuredGrid>
    <Piece NumberOfPoints="#" NumberOfCells="0">
      <Points>
          <DataArray type="Float32" NumberOfComponents="3" format="ascii">
          //point data//
          </DataArray>
      </Points>
      <Cells>
          <DataArray type="Int32" Name="connectivity" .../>
          <DataArray type="Int32" Name="offsets" .../>
          <DataArray type="UInt8" Name="types" .../>
      </Cells>
      <PointData>
          <DataArray Vectors="MyVector">
            //Vector data goes here//
          </DataArray>
      </PointData>
      <CellData/>
    </Piece>
  </UnstructuredGrid>
</VTKFile>
```

**Update**: As discussed in the comments, the `Cells` element must be specified (the `CellData` element can be left empty, as only point data is being speicifed). The `Cells` element specifies the cell types, connectivity and offsets. For a series of unconnected points (i.e. particles) this information is specified as arrays of length `n`, where `n` is the number of data points and where

```
type = 1, 1, .... 1
connectivity = 0, 1, 2, ... n
offsets = 1, 2, 3, ... n
```

Comment: This exactly what I want, only that I get en error message when trying this code, saying that "A piece is missing its Cells element". do you know anything about that?

Comment: Try replacing `<CellData></CellData>` with `<CellData/>` and `<Cells></Cells>` with `<Cells/>`. If that works I will update my answer.

Comment: no that didn't work either :( It is still nagging about cells element.

Comment: What is nagging - a program you are using? A little more information would be useful. Also, can you upload the file you are writing somewhere (maybe update your question if it is not too big). Then others can try opening/editing/debugging the file - without seeing the file it is hard to know what is going wrong.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, paraview is nagging :) I uploaded the basic form of the file in the question. there is a lot of points, so I left iut the numbers, but I'm pretty sure they are correct :-P

Comment: Ok, my bad: you can leave `<CellData/>` as it is as you are only defining point data. However, you still need to define the `<Cells>` information, that is the cell types, connectivity and offsets. I don't have the time to delve into this too much, so have a read of the file formats document yourself. As a first step, this information for an unconnected series of points (i.e. particles) is `type=1, 1, .... 1`, `connectivity=0, 1, 2, ... n ` and `offsets=1, 2, 3, ... n`. All these lists have a length n, where n is the number of points in your data.

Comment: Thankyou! after a little more debugging of the text in the files, it now works :)

Comment: No prolem - glad to help. Just so the answer is the correct one, are you using the structured or unstructured data format?